# Prevent animation jump when making div fixed

Tags: javascript, css, transition, floating

I'm working on a floating div effect where the div will move to the top bottom when scrolling down. The problem is when you scroll down and click the button to make the div fixed the animation just jumps out of order. it should move to the old position smoother.

```
<div id="container">
  <button id="toggleFix" onclick="document.querySelector('#element').classList.toggle('fixed')">Make the div fixed</button>
  <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var el = document.querySelector("#element"),
elPos = el.getBoundingClientRect();

el.style.left = elPos.left + "px";
el.style.right = elPos.right + "px";
el.style.top = elPos.top + "px";
el.style.bottom = elPos.bottom + "px";
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ajWaaM

```js
var el = document.querySelector("#element"),
  elPos = el.getBoundingClientRect();

el.style.left = elPos.left + "px";
el.style.right = elPos.right + "px";
el.style.top = elPos.top + "px";
el.style.bottom = elPos.bottom + "px";
```

```css
body {
  height: 150vh;
}

#container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

#toggleFix {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}

#element {
  background: black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

#element.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 845px !important;
  left: 10px !important;
  right: auto !important;
  bottom: 10px !important;
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 150px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="toggleFix" onclick="document.querySelector('#element').classList.toggle('fixed')">Make the div fixed</button>
  <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain the result of pressing the button a bit more precisely? Your JS and CSS seem to contradict each other.

Comment: Im just trying to fix the div at the bottom left part of the page, when removing the class which makes it the is not going correctly there but the animation is all out of order

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are moving the element off-screen (`top: 845px !important`).

Replacing this with `top: auto !important` will move the element to the bottom left-hand corner and it will stay there even when scrolling.

Note: This may/will affect the rest of your page layout.

Comment: I guess that's wanted. OPs problem is, that the animation to get it back isn't smooth. It just jumps to the position and grows in size. 
Am trying to solve this atm.

Answer (score 1):

In order to `transition` the position effectively, you have to have at least one of the four locations set (`top,left,right or bottom`).

Also I don't think you need JS for that. I managed to achieve this without js.

[Here's the CodePen to play with](https://codepen.io/DeeLiciouz/pen/LBygqW)

```css
body{
 height: 150vh; 
}
#toggleFix {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
}
#element{
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 450px;
  background: black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#element.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  top: 845px ;
  left: 10px ;
  right: auto ;
  bottom: 10px ;
  width: 200px ;
  height: 150px ;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="toggleFix" onclick="document.querySelector('#element').classList.toggle('fixed')">Make the div fixed</button>
  <div id="element">
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: You could use a absolute position for your div, but then the container would be useless. Unfortunately this is the only way I got it to work at the moment. For further solving I'd have to dive deeper into it.

Comment: Thanks, but what about if the div is in a contaner, the page jumps again

Comment: @Eli Can you clarify that for me? I don't understand, what you mean. Do you want the element to vanish completely, or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I see, the problem is, that as soon as you change the `position`-attribute the element's getting free from the container and jumps to the relative position, but relative to the body, instead of the container. I'll try to see how we can solve this.

Comment: I edited the answer and the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/DeeLiciouz/pen/LBygqW). I used `position:absolute` to free the element from the container, but I don't think ,that this is in your interest. It's a workaround for now, but if you depend on the container for whatever reason then you've to look at it again.